# OpsCenter nodes list shows all nodes names as localhost

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have a brand new cluster running DSE 5.0.3 with OpsCenter 6.0.3. I used the LifeCycle Manager to create a 6 node cluster, adding their IPs to the Nodes list and installing DSE on each node that way. The cluster seems fine, healthy, etc. but the Nodes section, under the LIST tab, shows all nodes' names as localhost. If I click on each node it shows "localhost - x.x.x.x" (x.x.x.x being the actual node IP). How do I make them show their actual hostnames in OpsCenter? Where does this name come from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostnames in OpsCenter are reported by the agent running on each node in the cluster. In this case each individual name is reporting its hostname as localhost. Fixing that configuration and restarting the agents should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! But where do I fix that? Runing `hostname` on the nodes returns something like "ip-10-1-10-91.localdomain", not localhost. What file is the opscenter/datastax agent name driven by?

Comment: Basically, its using the java call of "InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()", which in turn is doing a DNS lookup. Probably the easiest way to fix that would be to update or edit the /etc/hosts file on the nodes.

Comment: That did it, thank you! /etc/hosts had only "ip.address servername" and /etc/hostname had "servername.localdomain". Adding "servername.localdomain" to the hosts file line starting with the server IP took care of it.